# Why did the guy on Shabbat 127b change the order of events?

Tags: agada-stories-legends, maseches-shabbos

The following story appears in the Babylonian Talmud on [Shabbat 127b](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=127b&format=pdf):

> Our Rabbis taught: He who judges his neighbour in the scale of merit is himself judged favourably. Thus a story is told of a certain man who descended from Upper Galilee and was engaged by an individual in the South for three years. On the eve of the Day of Atonement  he requested him, 'Give me my wages that I may go and support my wife and children.' 'I have no money,' answered he. 'Give me produce,' he demanded; 'I have none,' he replied. 'Give me land.' — 'I have none.' 'Give me cattle.' — 'I have none. 'Give me pillows and bedding.' — 'I have none.' [So] he slung his things behind him and went home with a sorrowful heart.  After the Festival his employer took his wages in his hand together with three laden asses, one bearing food, another drink, and the third various sweetmeats, and went to his house. After they had eaten and drunk, he gave him his wages. Said he to him, 'When you asked me, "Give me my wages," and I answered you, "I have no money," of what did you suspect me?' 'I thought, Perhaps you came across cheap merchandise and had purchased it therewith.' 'And when you requested me, "Give me cattle," and I answered, "I have no cattle," of what did you suspect me?' 'I thought, they may be hired to others.' 'When you asked me, "Give me land," and I told you, "I have no land," of what did you suspect me?' 'I thought, perhaps it is leased to others.' 'And when I told you, "I have no produce," of what did you suspect me?' 'I thought, Perhaps they are not tithed.' 'And when I told you, "I have no pillows or bedding," of what did you suspect me?' 'I thought, perhaps he has sanctified all his property to Heaven.' 'By the [Temple] service!' exclaimed he, 'it was even so; I vowed away all my property because of my son Hyrcanus, who would not occupy himself with the Torah, but when I went to my companions in the South they absolved me of all my vows. And as for you, just as you judged me favourably, so may the Omnipresent judge you favourably.'
>
> ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/shabbath/shabbath_127.html#PARTb))

When the interaction first occurred the order of requests was:

1. Money
2. Produce
3. Land
4. Cattle
5. Pillows and bedding

Yet when the guy later paid up the wages and asked the employee what his reactions were, the order is different:

1. Money
2. Cattle
3. Land
4. Produce
5. Pillows and bedding

The first and last remain the same but the middle three have had their order reversed. Is there a reason for this? Have any commentaries addressed this?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the Talmud printings may have been based on MSS that had copyist errors. At least one such manuscript was preserved and can be found on the Genizah website, MS CUL: T-S F 2(2).75 (the part mentioning land in the first half of the story wasn't preserved, but you can tell that it's supposed to be there by the context):

> "תנו רבנ' הדן את חבירו לכף זכות דנין אותו לזכות ומע?ש?ה באדם ?א?חד שירד מגליל העל?יון ונשכר? אצל בעל הבית אחד בדרום שלש שנים ?ע?רב יום הכיפורים אמ' לו תן לי ש?כ?רי ו?אל?.. ............ את אשתי ואת בניי אמ' לו א?י?.. .............. אמ' לו תן לי פירות אין לי תן לי.. ................. לי בהמה אין לי תן לי כרים ו?כ?.. ............... הפשיל כליו לאחוריו והלך ...................לאחר הרגל נטל שכרו בי?דו?.. ................. שלש חמרים אחד של מא?כ?.. ................ משתה ואחד של מיני מג?ד?.. ................. אחר שאכלו ושתו נתן לו שכ.............. בשעה שאמרת לי תן לי שכרי ואמרת.. לך אין לי מעות במה חשדתני אמרתי שמא פרקמטיא ב?ז?ול נזדמנה לך ול..?ח'? בהן ובשעה שאמרת לי תן לי בהמה ואמרתי לך אין לי בהמה במה חשדת?ני? אמרתי שמא מושכרות ביד אח?ר?ים ?בשע'? שאמרת לי תן לי קרקע ואמרתי לך ...... לי קרקע אמרתי מחוכרות הן ביד אחרים וכשאמרתי לך אין לי פירות במה חש.. ........ אמ' שמא אינן מעושרות ובש?עה?.. ........... ?ש?אמרתי לך אין לי כרים וכסתות ?במה?.. ........."

However, the correct versions were preserved in one manuscript that's considered to be more accurate than most, MS Oxford 366:

> "הדן את חברו לכף זכות ת"ר הדן את חברו לזכו' דנין אותו לכף זכות ומעשה באדם אחד שירד מגליל העליון ונשכר אצל בעל הבית בדרום שלש שנים וערב יום הכפורים אמ' לו תן את שכרי ואלך ואזון את אשתי ואת בני אמ' לו אין לי מעות תן לי בהמה אמ' לו אין לי תן לי קרקע אמ' לו אין לי תן לי פירות אמ' לו אין לי תן לי כרים וכסתות אמ' לו אין לי מה עשה הפשיל כליו לאחוריו והלך לביתו בפחי נפש. ולאחר הרגל נטל שכרו עמו בידו ומשאוי שלשה חמ[ו]רים אחד של מאכל ואחד של מיני בגדים והלך לביתו ואכלו ושתו לאחר שאכלו ושתו נתן לו שכרו אמ' לו בשעה שאמרת לי תן לי שכרי ואמרתי לך אין לי במה חשדתני אמרתי שמא פרקמטיא בזול נזדמן לו לרבי ליקח ולקח בהן ובשעה שאמרת לי תן לי בהמה ואמרתי לך אין לי במה חשדתני אמרתי שמא מושכרות הן ביד אחרים ובשעה שאמרת תן לי קרקע ואמרתי אין לי במה חשדתני אמרתי שמא אינן מעושרין ובשעה שאמרת לי תן לי כרים וכסתות ואמרתי לך אין לי במה חשדתני אמרתי שמא הקדיש רבי כל נכסיו לשמים"

and also in MS Vatican 108:

> "תנו רבנן הדן את חבירו לכף זכות דנין אותו לכף זכות מעשה באדם אחד שירד מגליל העליון ונשכר אצל בעל הבית בדרום שלש שנים בערב יום הכפורים א' לו תן לי שכרי ואפרנס אשתי ובני א' לו אין לי מעות תן לי בהמה א' לו אין לי תן לי קרקעות א' לו אין לי א' לו תן לי פירות א' לו אין לי תן לי כרים וכסתות א' לו אין לי הפשיל כליו לאחוריו והלך לביתו בפחי נפש אחר הרגל נטל [בעל] הבית שכרו ועמו משאוי שלש חמורים אחד של מאכל ואחד של משתה ואחד של מיני מגדים והלך לביתו לאחר שאכלו ושתו (?א'?) נתן לו שכרו משלם וא' לו בשעה שאמרת(י) לי תן לי מעות ואמרתי לך אין לי במה חשדתני א' לו שמא פרקמטיא בא לך ולקח בהן בשעה שאמרת תן לי בהמה ואמרתי אין לי במה חשדת' א' לו שמא מושכרות הן ביד אחרים בשעה שאמרת תן לי קרקעות ואמ' אין לי במה חשדת' א' לו שמא (אינ?ן? ........... ..ן ........ ..ת)[מוחכרות הן ביד אחרי]ם בשעה שאמרת תן לי פירות ואמרתי אין לי במה חשדת' א' לו שמא אינן מעושרין (ב)[כ]שאמרת תן לי כרים וכסתות ואמרתי אין לי במה חשדתני אמרתי שמא הקדיש ר' כל נכסיו לשמים"

Interestingly, another very accurate manuscript is MS Munich 95, which has the same order but doesn't mention produce in the first part of the story, yet does in the second part:

> "תנו רבנן הדן את חבירו לכף זכות דנין אותו לזכות מעשה באדם אחד שירד מגליל העליון ונשכר אצל בעל הבית אחד שבדרום בשלש שנים ערב יום הכפורים א(ל)[מ'] לו תן לי שכרי ואלך ואיזון אשתי ובניי אמ' לו מעות אין לי [תן לי בהמות אין לי] תן לי קרקעות אמ' לו אין לי תן לי כרים וכסתות אין לי הפשיל כליו לאחוריו והלך לביתו בפחי נפש אחר הרגל נטל שכרו בידו ועמו משואי של חמורים אחד משל מאכל ואחד משל משתה ואחד משל מיני בגדים והלך לביתו לאחר שאכלו ושתו נתן לו שכרו אמ' לו בשע(ת)[ה] שאמרת תן לי שכרי ואמרתי לך אין לי מעות במה חשדתני אמרתי שמא פרקמטיא בזול ?[נ?זד?מן לך ולקח בהן] (הן) בשעה שאמרת לי תן לי בהמה במה חשדתני או' שמא מ[ו]שכ(י)רות הן ביד אחרים בשעה שאמרת לי תן לי קרקע במה חשדתני אמרתי שמא מו[2]כ[1]חרות הן ביד אחרים [בשעה שאמרת תן לי פירות ואמרתי לך אין לי במה חשדתני אמרתי שמא אינן מעושרין] ובשעה שאמרת לי תן לי כרים וכסתות ואמרתי אין לי במה חשדתני אמרתי שמא (..)[ה]קד[י]ש כל נכסיו לשמים"